# Search specified row for specific text

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

If Text"A" from WorkBook1 is found in ColB in WorkBook2, search a range of columns **from the ROW** from WorkBook2 in which Text"A" was found to find Text"B".

Essentially, I have two spreadsheets, linked by a common identifier (Person who completed the job).  In WorkBook2, people can be certified for a myriad of different tasks and their certification codes are stored in columns AN:HP.  WorkBook1 contains completed jobs, which person completed the job, and what the type of job was.  I want to search WorkBook2 to see if the person who completed the job was certified for that type of job.  The difficulty is that each individual can hold up to 20 different certification codes.

I currently can find the row in WorkBook2 where the person (Text"A") is listed from column H in WorkBook1 `=MATCH(H2,'[WorkBook2]Sheet1'!$B:$B,0)` Now I need to use that row number as the array to search in WorkBook2 for certification type (Text"B") found in [WorkBook1]Sheet1'!T2

Answer (score 0):

You've managed to get the first part right which is to use a `MATCH()` to return the row where the person is listed. You can use the `OFFSET()` function to create a dynamic range based on that row number.

`OFFSET()` take a range and then offset it by a number of rows or columns.

`OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])`

So you could create a reference to the row you want with

`OFFSET([Workbook2]Sheet1!$AN$1:$HP$1,MATCH(H2,'[WorkBook2]Sheet1'!$B:$B,0)-1,0)`

This works by setting a starting range as AN1:HP1 and then shifting it down by the row number returned from the `MATCH` *less 1*. If we didn't subtract one we would overshoot by one row.

You can then use a match to find the certification.

`=MATCH(T2,OFFSET([Workbook2]Sheet1!$AN$1:$HP$1,MATCH(H2,'[WorkBook2]Sheet1'!$B:$B,0)-1,0),0)`